# how to setup openshift wordpress setup on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, openshift

I am amazed that no information on how to setup openshift wordpress in local environment.

They also don't have full wordpress structure to set it up on localhost.
Their information on the site also not clear on this.

is there any steps to follow this?

Answer (score 4):

have you look at their github account? they have openshift quick start for wordpress here:

https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart

install client tool here:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html

**UPDATES:**
if you are looking for host your own OpenShift, then you should look at OpenShift Origin:

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html

Comment: it does not tell how to setup local environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can run openshift in a virtual machine.

see [this](https://www.openshift.org/vm/).

But there is no reason why you shouldn't use a free openshift account and build it from your local machine (with git). It is a hassle at first but if you master it you won't have to reinvent the wheel when going live.

edit: focus on getting it to work on openshift, there should be a lot of documentation on it. The local environment is just your git repo running on your local machine.